# Windows EventLog cannot exceed 32766 characters

Tags: asp.net, event-log

when i write log to windows eventlog:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SourceName", a_long_string);
```

i got the following exception:

> Log entry string is too long. A string written to the event log cannot exceed 32766 characters.

then i splits my log message into 2 or more string. but i don't think it is a good idea.
any workarounds? (such as extern the limit per log entry)

Comment: I would question the usability of a system that requires writing entries this long to the eventlog.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on event logging api claims that on post-vista computers the limit is in fact `31839` Thus .net check for `32766` and corresponding `ArgumentException` is incorrect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Event Log isn't intended for storing Chapter 1 of War and Peace.  You really should reconsider what you're writing to the event log.

If you want to log something voluminous (e.g. a crash dump), you can always store it somewhere on disk and write a message to the EventLog something like `Generated dump at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\MyApp\WarAndPeace.pdf`.

Comment: I may be the minority but, I am not fond of a diagnostics component used to record errors effectively masking the actual reason for logging a potential fault. If War and Peace is not possible then truncate the message with an indication of the message modification. I don't disagree that the messages should be constrained and/or logged using a different medium. This exception forces everyone who has ever written a trace in your application including 3rd parties to constrain the string using the default event log listener.[Bug?](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790768)